# Getting Image from ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gallery

I have a gallery that shows an array of images, when clicked they are displayed in an imageview. I want to be able to SHARE the image that is currently being displayed in an intent chooser. I can't figure out how to select the current image.

Gallery code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 120));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

        return imageView;
    }
```

Intent chooser code:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/png");

            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    Uri.parse("android.resource://com.appinfluence.fanapp.v1/drawable/" + Integer.toString(R.drawable.alright)));

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Where it says R.drawable.alright I need that to be a variable of the current image somehow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

To fetch currently selected view use

```
Gallery.getSelectedView();
```

and for getting Drawable from imageView use:

```
ImageVIew.getDrawable()
```

If you want to get inputstream from the drawable use following:

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable);
Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable .getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
```

Comment: So how do I get the current imageview image into a string. For example R.drawable.alright from my code above. Using imageview.getdrawable.tostring() i get android.drawable.BitmapDrawable@414743f8

Comment: Though I haven't used, just try by using:  resources .getResourcePackageName(resId) + '/' + 
resources.getResourceTypeName(resId) + '/' + 
resources.getResourceEntryName(resId);

Comment: where i can found drawable varible on this program

Answer (score 5):

```
    l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            String textViewString=textView.getText().toString();
            Bitmap image=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            DialogClass dialogClass=new DialogClass(MainActivity.this,image,textViewString);
            dialogClass.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

**My Best Function**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView imgView,bitmap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        bitmap=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bitmap);

        //set view to bitmap image
        bitmap.setImageBitmap(convertImageViewToBitmap(imgView));
    }

    //function to convert imageView to Bitmap

    private Bitmap convertImageViewToBitmap(ImageView v){

        Bitmap bm=((BitmapDrawable)v.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        return bm;
    }

}
```